# Booting option in windows 10 laptop

Tags: dual-boot

First off all, i am a novice of Linux so ignore any mistakes in my question.

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows-10 laptop. I want to use both of them on the same machine. When ever I start the computer it is directly going to Windows login. I have to go to boot options of HP and have to select Ubuntu partition to login to Ubuntu.

I want to enable a menu option while startup which will ask which OS to boot and login.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is Fast Startup turned off in Windows and is Secure Boot turned off in your BIOS settings?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did on my laptop with pre-installed w8 (upgraded to w10)

```
step 1: download the live cd
step 2: boot into environment (aka try it first)
step 3: install through the environment
step 4: select install next to windows
step 5: do not reboot the computer when the installation is done
step 6: open a terminal in the live environment and do the following

terminal step 1 (calling it tstep now): type sudo su
tstep 2: apt-get install efibootmgr
tstep 3: efibootmgr
```

and then make sure that ubuntu is first boot, you might need to edit that in your BIOS, after that you are good to go :)